# Using gridfs to store uploaded file with its metadata in Node / Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, gridfs

I know there's a few threads about this, but I couldn't find my answer exactly. So using post i have managed to get this file object to the server side

```
{ fileToUpload:
{ name: 'resume.pdf',
 data: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0a 25 c4 e5 f2 e5 eb a7 f3 a0 d0 c4 c6 0a 34 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 20 2f 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 20 35 20 30 20 52 20 2f 46 69 ... >,
 encoding: '7bit',
 mimetype: 'application/pdf',
 mv: [Function] } }
```

How do I save this along with the metadata using mongoose & gridfs? In most threads I've looked at so far, gridfs-stream was used given a temporary path of the file, which I don't have. Could someone help me save this file by streaming the data along with its metadata + given an example of how I would retrieve it & send it back to the clientside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must've been tired, I was using the express-fileupload as a middleware but not using it to save the file which is done with the mv function in the object. Using code below to save file locally and then streaming it to mongo using gridfs-stream

```
var file = req.files.fileToUpload;
file.mv('./uploads/'+file.name, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err, 500);
    }
    else {
        res.send('File uploaded!');
        var gfs = Grid(conn.db);

        // streaming to gridfs
        //filename to store in mongodb
        var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: file.name
        });
        fs.createReadStream('./uploads/'+file.name).pipe(writestream);

        writestream.on('close', function (file) {
            // do something with `file`
            console.log(file.filename + ' Written To DB');
        });
    }
});
```